# Roku: Playback is not smooth on Roku-4 device for 1080p@60fps HEVC content

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am running "customvideoplayer" sample application present inside roku SDK on a Roku-4 device.

I got the roku SDK from this link: http://wwwimg.roku.com/static/sdk/RokuSDK.zip

I am testing a 1080p@60fps HEVC stream. The Roku-4 is connected to a 1080p@60fps TV. The issue is that the playback is not smooth. I can see some frames are rendered for more time compare to others.

My questions are:

1) According to Roku documentation(Link: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Video+Encoding+Guidelines), Roku-4 supports upto 3840x2160 and upto 60fps for HEVC. Does it mean it supports 3840x2160 @ 60fps?

2) I am not observing any issue with 1080p@30fps stream. So, In the sample application, do I need to set any fields or enable any flags additionally to play 60fps content?

Comment: Good griffin, don't look at that ancient ZIP file - that's 3 years old! RokuCo does not release these wrongly-labeled "SDK" zips anymore - everything is on the web - documentation and sample apps. 

There is no separate downloadable SDK. Start untangling from https://sdkdocs.roku.com/

Comment: Thank you @NasBanov!! I read the documents and I have some questions. I posted a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781614/roku-how-to-use-ishd-fullhd-framerate-parameters . Could you please look into this?

Comment: I am not an expert on video - or i would have answered. My take would be "do not set any flags, unless you have to", i.e. always try first with default settings and if something is not quite there, set some flags as hint for the player